# Replacing class name in serialized data

Tags: java, serialization, refactoring

I want to replace the String "com.oldpackage.className" with "com.newPackage.className" in a stream of serialized data. This serialized data is read from the DB and updated after replacing the string.

I am facing some problems while doing the same. If you already guessed it, this is part of a refactoring exercise. Are there any libraries that would help me in manipulating the serialized data? If you can also please comment on any precautions or caveats, it would be of great help.

Thanks a lot,
Chris.
P.S: Both the old class and the new class do not declare a serialversion ID as part of its fields.

Comment: If the name of the enum is com.oldPackage.Person and the new name is com.newPack.Person what else should I be replacing in the serialized data:
1) replace com.oldPackage.Person with com.newPack.Person
2) replace com/oldPackage/Person with com/newPack/Person

Comment: Since there is also a class called com.oldPackage.PersonDetails and that would be affected by the above operations, I do the following:

3) replace com.newPack.PersonDetails(result of 1) with com.oldPackage.PersonDetails
4) replace com/newPack/PersonDetails((result of 2)) with com/oldPackage/PersonDetails

Can you please help me if I am missing anything?

Answer (score 5):

I do not know how to do what your are trying but I can suggest you "legal" solution. Implement convertor that has both old and new packages in classpath and does the following: reads data from DB, de-serializes it using the old package, converts old instances to new in java and then stores new data in DB again.

This solution requires performing some dirty job but it is safe. Moreover the results may be reused in future. But I wish you good luck to find solution that just replaces class name in serialized data.

Comment: Alex, that was my first approach and that is still alive. But the problem is, the serialized data is a hibernate proxy and I am facing too many issues with the first approach. I find the approach of replacing the package name in the serialized data as easy and theoretically feasible, however, I am looking out for any caveats or tricks that others know.

Comment: OK, good luck. I just think that name replacement will probably work if old and new name have the same length. Otherwise I am expecting problems.

Comment: Spot on, I faced issues with the replacement in both sql as well as Java side(using JDBC). On Java side it could have been because of the transformation to and from the resultset. In DB, which i was banking on, gave issues exactly for the reason you mention.

Answer (score 5):

To precise Tom Hawtin's reply, I have managed to implement it using the following code:

```
public static ObjectInputStream getSwapOIS( InputStream in ,String fromClass,String toClass)
    throws IOException ,ClassNotFoundException {
    final String from="^"+fromClass,fromArray="^\\[L"+fromClass,toArray="[L"+toClass;
    return new ObjectInputStream(in) {
        protected Class<?> resolveClass(ObjectStreamClass desc)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
        {
            String name = desc.getName().replaceFirst(from, toClass);
            name = name.replaceFirst(fromArray, toArray);
            return Class.forName(name);
        }
        protected ObjectStreamClass readClassDescriptor()
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
        {
            ObjectStreamClass cd = super.readClassDescriptor();
            String name = cd.getName().replaceFirst(from, toClass);
            name = name.replaceFirst(fromArray, toArray);
            if(!name.equals(cd.getName())) {
                cd = ObjectStreamClass.lookup(Class.forName(name));
            }
            return cd;
        }
    };
}
```

Note that you also need to override readClassDescriptor(). It works for both standard types and arrays and you can even change the class name not just the package name. Just do:

```
 InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(classBytes);
 ObjectInputStream ois = getSwapOIS(    in,
                                        "com.oldpackage.className",
                                        "com.newpackage.newClassName");
 Object myObject= ois.readObject();
```

Answer (score 3):

IIRC you can (with sufficient permissions) override `ObjectInputStream.resolveClass` (and `resolveProxyClass`) to return a `Class` with a different package names. Although, IIRC, you cannot change the simple class name.

Comment: And this what the Java docs say about enums: "The process by which enum constants are deserialized cannot be customized: any class-specific readObject, readObjectNoData, and readResolve methods defined by enum types are ignored during deserialization."

Comment: @ChrisOdney I wasn't suggesting using those methods.

Answer (score 2):

Can i suguest an alternative tack. The java serialisation format has some significant issues when being used for long term storage.

Since you are refactoring and are most likely going to have to deserialise all the stored data one way or another, you may want to look at [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) as an alternative serialisation format.

It might take a bit more work but it is designed specifically for long term storage and versioning.

Good luck

Comment: Gareth, I cannot think of an alternative serialization mechanism until I get this current data deserialized.

Comment: Surely just use the orignal classes in a one time batch job?

Answer (score 1):

If the data-to-be-refactored is being stored - in string form - in a database, one option is to use SQL to simply update that data, e.g., (in pseudo MySQL)

```
update mydata 
set serialized_data = 
replace(serialized_data, "com.oldpackage", "com.newpackage")
```

you would, of course, refactor your Java code before attempting to re-read this data from the DB.

Comment: he stores serializable java objects. Are you sure that simple string replacement will work, i.e. will not break java serialization?

Comment: It should work fine -- there's simply no other information in the serialized form that would contradict the update, which is the key issue, along with the assumption that the actual code is refactored before re-reading the data.   In that form, the data is self describing.   I would recommend XStream as a serializer/deserializer, although there are others.

Comment: My classname is something like com.oldpackageName.Person, I am trying to replace this with  com.newpackageName.Person. Unfortunaltely even com.oldpackageName.PersonDetails is getting replaced to com.newpackageName.PersonDetails. I am working on that. And also I need to see if serialized data contains the format of com/oldpackage/ in its data(. instead of the / for the VM).

Comment: It is giving me a java.io.UTFDataFormatException when i try to read it bck frm the DB

Answer (score 0):

I took a similar approach than @ehubin in my open source project, however, creating a new class descriptor might result in an error on deserialization, as the `ObjectStreamClass` object has an internal state / some flags, that are required for deserialization. If you create a new descriptor these internal flags are lost, resulting in an error. I implemented a [`LegacyObjectInputStream`](https://github.com/kristian/JDigitalSimulator/blob/e032071801fb92eb56a83317614bb70a2f65dcf3/src/main/java/lc/kra/jds/Utilities.java#L444) that is able to rename a class / package while deserializing it from stream. You should be easily able to adapt it to your use-case. Here is the class:

```java
public static class LegacyObjectInputStream extends AlternateClassLoaderObjectInputStream {
    public static final String LEGACY_PACKAGE_PREFIX = "de.ksquared.", PACKAGE_PREFIX = "lc.kra.";
    public LegacyObjectInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        super(in, getSimpleClassLoader());
    }
    @Override protected ObjectStreamClass readClassDescriptor() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ObjectStreamClass descriptor = super.readClassDescriptor(); String name = descriptor.getName();
        if(name.contains(LEGACY_PACKAGE_PREFIX)) {
            String newName = replaceLegacyPackage(name);
            try {
                // do not return a new ObjectStreamClass looked up from new class definitions, but modify the descriptor read from the stream, otherwise some flags could be wrong, like the flag "hasWriteObjectData" resulting in an exception when trying to read the object
                Field nameField = ObjectStreamClass.class.getDeclaredField("name");
                nameField.setAccessible(true);
                nameField.set(descriptor, newName);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return descriptor;
    }
    public static String replaceLegacyPackage(String name) {
        return name.replaceFirst("^(\\[L)?"+Pattern.quote(LEGACY_PACKAGE_PREFIX), "$1"+Matcher.quoteReplacement(PACKAGE_PREFIX));
    }
}
```