# How to deal with a Java serialized object whose package changed?

Tags: java, serialization, versioning

I have a Java class that is stored in an HttpSession object that's serialized and transfered between servers in a cluster environment. For the purpose of this explanation, lets call this class "Person".

While in the process of improving the code, this class was moved from "com.acme.Person" to "com.acme.entity.Person". Internally, the class remains exactly the same (same fields, same methods, same everything).

The problem is that we have two sets of servers running the old code and the new code at the same time.
The servers with the old code have serialized HttpSession object and when the new code unserializes it, it throws a ClassNotFoundException because it can't find the old reference to com.acme.Person. At this point, it's easy to deal with this because we can just recreate the object using the new package. The problem then becomes that the HttpSession in the new servers, will serialize the object with the new reference to com.acme.entity.Person, and when this is unserialized in the servers running the old code, another exception will be thrown. At this point, we can't deal with this exception anymore.

What's the best strategy to follow for this kind of cases?
Is there a way to tell the new servers to serialize the object with the reference to the old package and unserialize references to the old package to the new one? 
How would we transition to using the new package and forgetting about the old one once all servers run the new code?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found this [blog post](http://www.norwinter.com/2009/08/20/refactor-serializable-java-class/) that claims to have a solution, though it doesn't spell it out very clearly.

What it is actually saying is that you create a subclass of `ObjectInputStream` that overrides the `readClassDescriptor` method to do something like this:

```
@Override
protected java.io.ObjectStreamClass readClassDescriptor() 
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ObjectStreamClass desc = super.readClassDescriptor();
    if (desc.getName().equals("oldpkg.Widget")) {
        return ObjectStreamClass.lookup(newpkg.Widget.class);
    }
    return desc;
};
```

---

You should also look at this [SO question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668675/replacing-class-name-in-serialized-data) which cover some of the same ground as your question.

My advice would be: **don't** support the case where old versions of software read data serialized by the new version.

- This is a good opportunity to encourage (actually force) people to upgrade to the latest version of the code-base.  Generally speaking, it is in *everyone's* interest that this happen sooner rather than later.
- If it is premature to force people to upgrade for other reasons, then (IMO) you should seriously consider *backing out* your changes to the class / package names.  Wait until you've got a clear strategy / plan for upgrading that is 1) technically sound, and 2) acceptable to all stakeholders.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to address only the case where the legacy class needs to be deserialized into the new class, but not serialized back into a compatible stream that servers with old code would understand. Maybe the same principle can apply, but I need to research this further. Thanks again for the link! :)

Comment: You may also have to add in logic to handle arrays of a changed class. The class name looks something like ``[Lpackage.class.name``

Comment: I would also add that once you do this, you can no longer add/delete fields from the class without causing errors when deserializing. I'm not sure why this occurs, but rather than ignoring deleted fields, for instance, it attempts to use the next available field, causing a ``ClassCastException``.

Comment: Yes. This is the solution to go also when you want to change the name of the class you want to deserialize into. Let's say you serialized with class A, but you want to deserialize into class B, you can do this.

Answer (score 3):

This is always a big headache with Java serialization. As long as you're migrating your classes anyway, I'd recommend looking into migrating toward a different serialization mechanism like XStream. There's an interesting [article on this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/migrate-serialized-java?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a+javalobby/frontpage+%28Javalobby+/+Java+Zone%29) at JavaLobby.

Comment: +1 - JSON could be another alternative.  Duck typing is your friend.

Comment: @duffymo - XStream supports output to JSON as well as XML.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'll do eventually, but for the time being, I need a more immediate solution without adding a new XML/JSON serialization mechanism. Thanks anyway.

Comment: we use xstream here and serialized to java before storing objects in databases. Works great. You can easily alter the stored object xml, or you can configure xstream to alias things like classes/fields/packages at runtime for you. Though you should probably bake such migrations directly into the data.

Answer (score 2):

You're screwed, bounce the old servers if you're happy to promote your changes. Any hack to achieve your goal will just add more crap code and makes for more mess and headaches.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases you don't have access to the ObjectInputStream, and you can't override `readClassDescriptor()`. For example, another subsystem serializes and deserializes these objects. In our case, we had legacy instances serialized in Quartz job data maps.

For this case, you have to maintain a shallow definition of the old class. You can implement the old class's `readResolve()` and `writeReplace()` methods.

```
class OldClass{
  private int aField;
  private Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
     return new NewClass(aField);
  }
  private Object writeReplace() throws ObjectStreamException {
     return new NewClass(aField);
  }
}
```