# Java objects cannot be deserialized after the packagename of a class has been changed. What can I do about it?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

As we know, when I deserialize a serialized Java object tree, all the classes in the tree has to be on the classpath. Hence, since someone has moved some classes into an other package, deserialization throws ClassNotFoundException.

My question would be, is there a simpler way to solve this, than implementing my own serialization/deserialization?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with a Java serialized object whose package changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305473/how-to-deal-with-a-java-serialized-object-whose-package-changed).  (The answer is "maybe", depending on the exact details.)

Comment: here is another thread that contains something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994054/how-to-deserialize-from-a-file-to-different-class

Comment: @Setphen, thanks for your comment, a quick search did not throw me that post. Anyway, I'm looking into it, if that helps me. Will follow up, possibly tomorrow.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I realize this question is possibly a duplicate. [Stephen's answer to a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5305751/176569) works for me fine, I can deserialize those classes that were moved to an other package. For the record, I put here the subclass of ObjectInputStream I use.

```
public class ClassNameMappingObjectInputStream extends ObjectInputStream {

    public static Map<String, Class> classNameMapping = initclassNameMapping(); 

    private static Map<String, Class> initclassNameMapping(){
        Map<String, Class> res = new HashMap<String, Class>();
        res.put("com.lsy.nlm.report.filter.Filter", com.lsy.nlm.filter.Filter.class);
        res.put("com.lsy.nlm.report.filter.FilterSummary", com.lsy.nlm.filter.FilterSummary.class);
        res.put("com.lsy.nlm.report.filter.TopFilter", com.lsy.nlm.filter.TopFilter.class);
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(res);
    }

    public ClassNameMappingObjectInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        super(in);
    }


    protected ClassNameMappingObjectInputStream() throws IOException, SecurityException {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected java.io.ObjectStreamClass readClassDescriptor() 
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ObjectStreamClass desc = super.readClassDescriptor();
        if (classNameMapping.containsKey(desc.getName())){
            return ObjectStreamClass.lookup(classNameMapping.get(desc.getName()));
        }
        return desc;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the [link provided above by Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5305751/697630) about changing the class descriptor is probably the best. I wish I had known that a few months ago when I had to implement something similar.

Although I am not sure it would have worked because in my case the original classes had evolved so much that they did not longer reflect the original structure and as such it would have required a lot of carpentry behind the scenes to make it work.

At any rate, recently I had to solve a similar problem. In my case I created a migrator class. In it I used seconday class loader to load an old version of my classes (the ones in the original package) and with them I extracted the information in the serialized objects and then copied it into the new versions of them (the ones in the new package structure). Unfortunately this copying could not be done without certain amount of Java reflection since I was working with two separate class loaders.