# Can two classes that are the same be serialized and unserialized?

Tags: java, class, object, serialization

So lets say I have a class in Java and it stores data and I take an object and serialized it and saved that into a file. And I have another project with the exact same class, but it was still defined in another file. Would I be able to take the file I save and unserialized it in the that project would it work?

Comment: I think this is one of those questions that can easily be answered by trying to do it. It'll either work or won't; it's highly unlikely to break in subtle ways.

Comment: Note: If you want to persist JavaBeans to external files, it's recommended to use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html instead of serialization. See also: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/articles-jsp-139072.html#javabeans

Answer (score 0):

I think as long as the class name and the `serialVersionUID` are the same, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that would work, assuming that the respective projects have the same (or compatible) ".class" files for the classes in question.

Serializing and then deserializing an object essentially creates a copy of it.  Object identity is not preserved when you serialize and then deserialize.  What is preserved is the state of the objects and the relationship with other objects in the serialization.

Contrast this with:

- orthogonal persistence - where the system ensure that there is only one object, and
- object relational mappings - where there are potentially multiple in-memory replicas, but the system can sync them with a "master" copy that lives in the database.

Answer (score 0):

This is what serialization is designed for. It allows you to pass objects from one Java app to another Java app working on different JVMs and different computers. It may be done thru a file or net or DB.

Answer (score -1):

If you specify [serialVersionUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), that would be possible.

> **UPD:** The stream-unique identifier is a 64-bit hash of the class name, interface class names, methods, and fields.

So if your classes implement different interfaces, you should face a problem. Any way specifying serialVersionUID for serializable classes is a good practice.

> Note - It is strongly recommended that all serializable classes explicitly declare serialVersionUID values, since the default serialVersionUID computation is highly sensitive to class details that may vary depending on compiler implementations, and can thus result in unexpected serialVersionUID conflicts during deserialization, causing deserialization to fail.

[Stream Unique Identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html#4100)

Comment: You don't actually need to *specify* it, as long as it's the same, and the fully qualified class name is the same.

Comment: Not only qualified name and methods matter.

Answer (score -1):

> I have another project with the exact same class, but it was still defined in another file.

In other words it is almost certainly a *different* class, unless the source code is declared to be in the same the package, in which case there was zero point in having it in two or more separate files in the first place. Similar source code in two different packages is not the same class, it is two different classes, and one cannot be deserialized as the other.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#6678 If input class has fewer fields then output, that would work, if they have same serialVersionUID.

Comment: @Noofiz Of course, but he has already said it is 'exactly the same class', and *that* is what I am questioning: specifically, the package statement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305473/how-to-deal-with-a-java-serialized-object-whose-package-changed

Comment: @Noofiz Yes, that is a solution to the problem I am describing.